# Find local min based on the length of occurences of successive means without falling in wrong min

Tags: algorithm, time-series

## 1. Problem description

I have the following list of values `[10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 10]` It is shown in the following picture.
[image]

What I want to do is find the minimum based on the value of the element and 
its duration. From the previous list we can construct the following dictionary **(key:val)** :`[10:4, 5:4, 7:2, 2:1, 4:1, 3:3, 10:1]`. Meaning we have 4 sucessive 10s followed by 4 successive 5s, 2 successive 7s and 3 successive 3s.

Based on what I said the local min is 5. But I don't want that The local min **should be 3**. **We didn't select 2** because it happened only once.

Do you have an idea on how we can solve that problem. Is there an existing method that can be used to solve it?

Of course we can sort the dictionary by values `[10:4, 5:4, 7:2, 3:3, 10:1]` and select the lowest key that has a value different than 1. Is that a good solution?

---

## 2. Selection criteria

- must be a local min (find_local_min(prices))
- must have the highest numbers of succession
- the min succession must be > 1
- **AND I AM STUCK!** because now I have 3 as local minimum but it is repeated only 3 times. I was testing if My idea is correct and I tried to find a counter example and I shot my foot

---

## 3. source code

the following code extracts the minimums with the dictionary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import sys
import os

from collections import defaultdict

def find_local_min(prices):
    i = 1
    minPrices = []
    while i < len(prices):
        if prices[i] < prices[i-1]:
            minPrices.append(prices[i])
            j = i + 1
            while j < len(prices) and prices[j] == prices[j-1]:   
                minPrices.append(prices[j])
                j += 1   
            i = j 
        else:
            i += 1
    return minPrices 


if __name__ == "__main__":

    l = [10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 2,4, 3, 3, 3, 10]
    minPrices = find_local_min(l)

    minPriceDict = defaultdict(int)
    for future in minPrices :
        minPriceDict[future] += 1

    print minPriceDict
```

---

> As output if gives the following: `defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2: 1, 3:
>   3, 5: 4})` Based on this output the algorithm will select 5 as the min
>   because it is repeated 5 successive times. **But that's wrong!** it
>   should be 3. **I really want to know how to solve that problem**

Comment: "based on the value of the element and its duration" - In what way, do you mean? i.e., why is 3 the local min and not 5? Is this based on total count or just consecutive occurrences?

Comment: yes exactly **total count or just consecutive occurrences**

Comment: I'm sorry, to me those seem mutually exclusive. And I'm still confused as to why 3 is the correct answer and 5 is not.

Comment: So, you want the first lowest number found that has length of more than one? What if, in this example, you had 4 which occurred 20 times. Would 3 still be the correct answer or would 4 then take precedence since it is so long? The constraints on this don't seem clear.

Comment: @HaniGotc Your explanation is bit unclear. Can you please mention the requirement in detail along with couple of sample input and output data?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh please check my question. Let me know if it's ok

Comment: sorry @KylonTyner for the confusion. I posted the code it will clarify my question

Comment: What is the clear criteria for selecting local min

Comment: @VidorVistrom check section 2

Comment: Simply compare the keys. The middle key should be smaller than previous and next key. And the value stored in middle key should be at least 2. Make a list of all these keys and select the smallest key.

Comment: @VidorVistrom listed the exactly solution I would propose. You should go this route.